# Is the H3Index ordered?

Tags: h3

Is the return value of java api kRingDistances orderly?

Does the H3Index of two adjacent cells have other H3Index?

for example,`List<List<Long>> result = h3.kRingDistances(index, k)`

here is the result: `[[613344576152797183], [613344576150700031, 613344574395383807, 613344575655772159, 613344575651577855, 613344576148602879, 613344576146505727], [613344576159088639, 613344574454104063, 613344574393286655, 613344574384898047, 613344574386995199, 613344575647383551, 613344575643189247, 613344575653675007, 613344576167477247, 613344576175865855, 613344576156991487, 613344576154894335]]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on the question, but two answers here:

- H3 indexes themselves are not ordered sequentially, but indexes that are numerically close to each other are also geographically close. There's an illustration of indexing order here: https://beta.observablehq.com/@nrabinowitz/h3-indexing-order
- The indexes from `kRing` are not in guaranteed order. The guarantees here are fairly well [explained in the docs](https://uber.github.io/h3/#/documentation/api-reference/traversal) - `kRing` output order is undefined. Other functions like `kRingDistances` can give you H3 indexes ordered by distance from the origin, but not necessarily ordered within the ring. `hexRange` and `hexRing` *do* guarantee ordered hexagons, but will fail with an error code if they encounter pentagon distortion.

Comment: Thanks!
I have doubts about this sentence: H3 indexes are created by taking the position number (0-6) of a given cell at each resolution of the H3 grid.

If the index of these 7 cells is [[613344576152797183], [613344576150700031, 613344574395383807, 613344575655772159, 613344575651577855, 613344576148602879, 613344576146505727]].
Is there another index such as 613344576146505717 between these indexes?

Because I want to store these indexes with Redis SortedSet, the score is these indexes. This will enable commands like Redis GEORADIUSBYMEMBER.

Comment: I just discovered H3 a couple of days ago and find the hexagonal approach very clever and appealing. Documentation is a bit terse for me, however, so if I may ask you here since you're one of the pioneers. I'm exploring H3 as a geoquery solution (and finally ditch the ugly geohash we're using now). Geoquerying (in NoSQL anyway) requires performing a single range operation on cell (hexagon) IDs. With H3, can we locate a hexagon, specify how many rings we want around it, and express all of those cells (center + rings) as a single range of hex IDs?

Comment: @hgale No, probably not. While H3 indexes that are close to each other numerically *are* close geographically, the reverse is not true - a hexagon may border another with a significantly different numeric address (eg if they are children of different base cells). There are various ways to use H3 as a fast geo index (probably worth a different SO question to elaborate), but numeric range isn’t going to be viable.

Comment: @BlastofTempest See my answer above. For any given k-ring, there is no guarantee that there are not other valid indexes numerically in between the indexes in the ring - for rings that cross base cells, there could be thousands, or millions at fine resolutions.